# How to calculate the total time duration with DAX measure in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have got the following table named *schedule*

| row number | Date | Status | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 16 July 2023 | Start Shift | 08:00:00 |
| 2 | 16 July 2023 | End Shift | 14:13:00 |
| 3 | 16 July 2023 | End Shift | 18:00:00 |
| 4 | 16 July 2023 | Start Shift | 22:00:00 |
| 5 | 16 July 2023 | Travel | 22:18:00 |
| 6 | 16 July 2023 | Arrived | 22:53:00 |
| 7 | 17 July 2023 | End Shift | 16:12:00 |
| 8 | 18 July 2023 | Start Shift | 07:00:00 |
| 9 | 18 July 2023 | Start Shift | 10:00:00 |
| 10 | 18 July 2023 | Arrived | 11:04:00 |
| 11 | 18 July 2023 | completed | 12:15:00 |
| 12 | 18 July 2023 | End Shift | 16:12:00 |

I want to create a measure using `DAX` formula to calculate the total time duration in between each pair of `Start Shift` and `End Shift`, and show it in number of hours and minutes, e.g. 14hr 38m
For the two or more consecutive `Start Shift` or `End Shift`, it is an error in the data so only the time duration in between each pair of `Start Shift` and `End Shift` is needed.

So for the above table, the result should be:
row 2 - row 1 = 6hr 13m
row 7 - row 4 = 18hr 12m
row 12 - row 9 = 6hr 12m
**Total = 30hr 37m**

I have tried many different ways to write the `DAX` formula and shows it using the Card visual, but the result either shows `(Blank)`, `0` or simply an error. I have limited permission to transform the data so I can only work on that using the `DAX` measure. What would be the correct approach and way to write the `DAX` formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something similar to:

```
Shift Duration =
  var endShifts = CALCULATETABLE(DISTINCT(schedule[row number]), schedule[Status] = "End Shift")
  var result = 
    SUMX(
      endShifts,
      (
        var curRow = [row number]
        var curEnd = CALCULATE(MIN([Date]) + MIN([Time]))
        var prvStart = TOPN(1, FILTER(ALL(schedule), schedule[row number] < curRow && schedule[Status] = "Start Shift"), [row number], DESC)
        var prvEnd = TOPN(1, FILTER(ALL(schedule), schedule[row number] < curRow && schedule[Status] = "End Shift"), [row number], DESC)
        var durMin = DATEDIFF(MINX(prvStart, [Date] + [Time]), curEnd, MINUTE)

        return IF(MINX(prvStart, [row number]) > MINX(prvEnd, [row number]), durMin)
      )
    )
  var resultH = QUOTIENT(result, 60)
  var resultM = MOD(result, 60)
  return IF(NOT ISBLANK(result), resultH & "hr " & resultM & "m")
```

[image]

Same code as above but with comments to help explain workings:

```
Shift Duration = 
  // Get list of rows numbers for End Shift
  var endShifts = CALCULATETABLE(DISTINCT(schedule[row number]), schedule[Status] = "End Shift")
  var result = 
    SUMX(
      // for each End Shift row - sum the following
      endShifts,
      (
        // the following is done for each End Shift row

        // store this row's row number
        var curRow = [row number]

        // store this row's end DateTime
        var curEnd = CALCULATE(MIN([Date]) + MIN([Time]))

        // get the first previous Start Shift row
        var prvStart = TOPN(1, FILTER(ALL(schedule), schedule[row number] < curRow && schedule[Status] = "Start Shift"), [row number], DESC)

        // get the first previous End Shift row
        var prvEnd = TOPN(1, FILTER(ALL(schedule), schedule[row number] < curRow && schedule[Status] = "End Shift"), [row number], DESC)

        // get diff minutes from this current End Shift row to the first previous Start Shift row
        var durMin = DATEDIFF(MINX(prvStart, [Date] + [Time]), curEnd, MINUTE)

        // only return a value if the previous row is Start Shift, and not End Shift (which should be ignored, in this example, ignore row number 3)
        return IF(MINX(prvStart, [row number]) > MINX(prvEnd, [row number]), durMin)
      )
    )
  var resultH = QUOTIENT(result, 60)
  var resultM = MOD(result, 60)
  return IF(NOT ISBLANK(result), resultH & "hr " & resultM & "m")
```

Comment: Hey Sam! If we declare a variable inside an iterator like `SUMX` does it re-evaluate each variable in each iteration?

Comment: Yes it does, and in this answer it dependant on it.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please explain how are you summing on a `CALCULATETABLE` and `TOPN` block? I'm unable to comprehend it how is it working?

Comment: I've updated the answer with code comments - hopefully that helps.

Comment: Great answer Sam. Have an upvote.

Comment: This is simply amazing! I was able to obtain the result but in a much more complicated way by adding a few new columns and then perform the calculation which is very low efficiency. You answer is just brilliant! Thank you Sam!